# Make a function output different results depending on rmarkdown output format

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've created a small function which, given a table as argument, outputs some HTML which allows to display different views of this table with a tabbed interface.

The problem is, this works nicely when rendering an HTML document, but breaks if I want to generate a PDF. The solution would be to make the function aware of the current rmarkdown output format to make it output the correct code. Something like this :

```
function() {
    if (current_output_format=="html") output_something_in_html()
    if (current_output_format=="pdf") output_something_in_latex()
}
```

So is there a way to determine, when calling `render()`, which output format is currently rendered ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A hacky solution is to use a `Makefile`. When compiling, create a temporary copy of the file for `pdf` output and set appropriate flags.

Comment: @csgillespie Yes, that's the way I deal with it for now, but it's not very "portable". Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What about  catching the error and dealing with it in a sensible way. So something like:

```
ans = try(do_default(), TRUE)
if(class(ans)== "try-error") 
    ans = do_fall_back()
```

Still not the best solution, but at least it's portable.

Comment: This could be a way, but my code doesn't raise any error. I just want to output something different (HTML or LaTeX) depending on the rendered format.

Comment: I'm all out of suggestions then :(